# jqPlot: print pointLabels from json file

Tags: ajax, json, file, external, jqplot

I'd like to render a chart from a `JSON` file with `jqPlot`.
With the help of some examples I came to the following code that work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot) {
    var ret = null;
    $.ajax({
        // have to use synchronous here, else returns before data is fetched
        async: false,
        url: url,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            ret = data;
        }
    });
    return ret;
};

var jsonurl = "./json_3.json";

plo12 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    title: 'User Activity Chart (AJAX JSON Data Renderer)',
    legend: {show:true},
    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker:true,
        pointLabels: { show:true } 
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                formatString:'%a %d %b %H:%M'
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickOptions: {
                show: false
            },
        }
    }
});
});
```

And the `JSON` file looks like this:

```
[
    [
        ["2012-02-07 10:00", 10, "start"],
        ["2012-02-07 23:43" ,10, "end"]
    ],
    [
        ["2012-02-07 01:45", 20, "start"],
        ["2012-02-07 08:18", 20, "end"]
    ]
 ]
```

This way I can draw as many series as I want.
The only problem now is that the labels (start/end) are not printed on the chart and I can't understand why.
I thought that this line of code was enough:

```
pointLabels: { show:true }
```

Any advice?

Comment: Stupid me!
Missing:
    jqplot.pointLabels.min.js

Comment: Since you solved it thus why don't you either add your comment as the answer to your question and accept it or remove the question all together if the problem was that simple?

Answer (score 3):

you should use:

```
    xaxis: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            formatString:'%H:%M'
        }
    },
```